# Is there anything in place to attract back past members of *this* community?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

It seems this site is down, maybe short of questions. I have a few question to ask here. I've started with [one question](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/ways-to-notify-interested-autistic-contacts-of-next-meetings) at first.

But how people could be notified of that question, if noone anymore comes back here ? I used the "@" in comments to notify some power users, is it a good thing or an abuse ?

Is there another way to notify users that I missed ?

PS: I just got the "you can only post once every 40 minutes" error: this is not going to help this community. Should I nevertheless submit a question for that   also ?

Comment: A side question would be if anyone here would be willing to be notified of *every* question on communitybuilding.SE to attrack faster answers to newcomers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to attract past *and* new member to this community is to **ask great questions**.  In particular, to ask questions that will hit the Hot Network Questions queue.

The Interpersonal Skills site appears very successful at hitting the Hot Network Questions queue.  A lot of community building is about interpersonal skills.  We ought to be able to hit this queue as well.  Some people might stay!

Answer (score -3):

A possible way would be to subvert the page of a question A on communitybuilding.meta.SE made for that purpose. Newcomers would post some question B on communitybuidling.SE, then, to notify about it, post an answer to that question A linking to their question B.

People willing to be notified of new questions on communitybuidling.SE would mark that question A as favorite.

As a possible bonus, when the newcomer isn't anymore interested for feedback for his question B(e.g., because no more useful for him), he would delete his answer to question A.

Do you like this ?

Comment: You can get an [RSS feed of questions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/feeds) now (link is at the bottom of the main page), and subscribe to the newsletter to get weekly email, and subscribe to tags of interest to get email within 15 minutes, 3 hours, or 1 day, or visit the main page once a day.  Do we need a manual method of pushing out notifications to accompany those?

Comment: @MonicaCellio You should post that as an answer so that I can accept it :-)

Comment: It doesn't seem like an answer to the question, which is about attracting people back.  I was just pointing out that the scheme you propose for people *who already want to follow the site* to do so is more complicated than it needs to be.